# linkTo/transitionTo: refreshing the route/model when the destination route is the same as the current one

Tags: ember.js

Currently transitioning to the current route doesn't do anything.

I have been trying to trigger a route/model refresh when the destination route of a `link-to` helper or the `transitionTo` method is the same as the `currentRouteName`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to trigger a full transition.
Have a look at the official guide:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/routing/query-params/#toc_opting-into-a-full-transition

Comment: This looks like what I need, but how to I do a full transition only when the target route is the same as the current route?